# Variable not getting Values

Tags: python, dataframe, categories

I have to make some categories like:

```
Less then 20         = Low
Between 20 and 1000  = Medium
Greater than 1000    = High
```

For that, I made a function `lable()` & it is working perfectly but when I am defining it in a new col, new col is not receiving that values.

```
    def lable(x):
     if x  < 20:
       print("Low")
     elif 20 <= x <= 1000:
       print("Medium")
     else:
       print("High")

    stack['Leval']=stack['CompanySizeNumber'].apply(lable)
```

I want to insert all these values in new col which I defined above. Kindly tell me reason that why it is not get assigned

Comment: change `print` to `return`

Answer (score 0):

This is not working as you are just printing on the function call rather than returning the number on function call.
You need to change your code with:

```
def lable(x):
    if x < 20:
        return "Low"
    if 20 <= x <= 1000:
        return "Medium"
    return "High"


stack['Leval'] = stack['CompanySizeNumber'].apply(lable)
```